# unsigned reference to unsigned long when compile c++ program

Tags: c++, c++14, size-t

I have a homework to deal with big number, but I cannot compile the most simple version of code. There are three files (.hh, .cpp and a test .cpp).
Codes here:
bignum.hh:

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>  // uint8_t

#include <iostream> // ostream

namespace bistro
{
    template <typename T = uint8_t>
    class BigNum
    {
    public:
        BigNum(std::size_t base);
    private:

    };
}
```

bignum.cpp:

```
#include "bignum.hh"

namespace bistro
{
    using std::size_t;

    // debug
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    template<typename T>
    BigNum<T>::BigNum(size_t base) {
        cout << base << endl;
    }
}
```

test0.cpp:

```
#include "../src/bignum.hh"

using bistro::BigNum;

int main() {
    BigNum<uint8_t> *b = new BigNum<>(10);
    return 0;
}
```

and I use this command to compile them:

```
g++ -std=c++14 src/bignum.cpp tests/test0.cpp -o tests/test0
```

Here is the problem:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9dzR.png)
So, where is the problem?

Comment: Please don't display text error messages as images - just copy and paste the error text into the question.

Comment: @Mat - it might be kind to give the user a link to a duplicate question

Comment: Ignore me.  The link is at the top!